# .htaccess to VueJS in non-root directory

Tags: vue.js, .htaccess, vuejs2

I have a problem with `.htaccess` for VueJS. I'm using the example available in the official documentation.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

It turns out that this example works perfectly in the root folder, but my front-end is in another folder, because on the root folder is the site's home page, which was not developed with VueJs. So I'm creating inside the `/admin` folder. The directory hierarchy looks something like this:

```
   /
    |_ /index.php
    |_ /.htaccess (to full site)
    |_ /admin
       |_ /.htaccess (to vue)
       |_ /index.html (vue page)
```

The problem is that if I access the browser `https://example.com/admin` works perfectly, but `https://example.com/admin/user` works only by clicking on the link contained in site body, which leads to this URI, but it does not work with direct browser access. Only the `index.html` page accepts direct access from the browser. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this problem? Try putting the `.htaccess` in the root folder and not in `/admin` folder, but it didn't work. I also tried replacing the `RewriteBase /` line to `RewriteBase /admin` but it didn't work.

The `.htaccess` file in root folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Basically removes the `.php` extension.

Comment: You need to include both `.htaccess` files in your question. Is `/admin` expected to be in the URL?

Comment: Basically removes the .php extension.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
> ```

If this `.htaccess` file is located inside the `/admin` subdirectory and `/admin` is part of the URL then it should be written as follows, otherwise, it will try to rewrite the request to `/index.html` in the document root, which presumably does not exist.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

The changes made:

- Remove the `RewriteBase` directive entirely.
- Remove the slash prefix from the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string. ie. `/index.html` becomes `index.html`. Rewriting to a relative path. This is a file-path relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file.
- The `DirectoryIndex` directive may not be required, depending on how this is configured in the server config.

Note that this will completely override the `.htaccess` file in the parent/root directory.

---

> I also tried replacing the `RewriteBase /` line to `RewriteBase /admin` but it didn't work.

That didn't work because of the slash prefix on `/index.html` (the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string. The `RewriteBase` only applies to relative path substitutions.

> Try putting the `.htaccess` in the root folder and not in `/admin` folder, but it didn't work.

You could do something like that, but you will need to modify the directives accordingly (it won't work as written). However, you could get conflicts, you might as well keep the sites/config separate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Vue JS routing to work well in a non root directory, you can use the following htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /folder/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /folder/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

In case you don't know where to put the ".htacesss" file with the above content:

- For older webpack put it near the index.html (in the src folder)
- For newer webpack and for VUE CLI / VITE put it inside the "public" folder